# GKPlayer, Game Center, Avatars

Tags: iphone

Does Game Center offer any support for player avatars, e.g in a multiplayer game?

If not, presumably an app will have to retrieve an avatar from the local device?

Comment: Removed the 'java' tag, didn't seem useful given the question.

Comment: Did I really write Java? Oh my! Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question. But just for new folks who stumble onto it: Check out the `GKPlayer` class reference, specifically the `loadPhotoForSize:withCompletionHandler:` method.